# SQL subquery: need two values returned

Tags: sql, derby

I'm trying to combine these two queries, but am having trouble because subqueries can only return one value.

I'm using Netbeans IDE, Java DB, and Apache Derby.

What I need returned is the author's first and last name, plus the number of books they've written--and only the one who has written the most:

```
SELECT AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || AUTHOR_LAST_NAME AS AUTHOR_NAME
FROM Authors
WHERE AUTHOR_ID = (SELECT AUTHOR_ID, COUNT(*) AS num_books_read
FROM Books
GROUP BY AUTHOR_ID
ORDER BY num_books_read DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY);
```

I've tried doing joins as well but can't get the result I need.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two values returned:

```
SELECT AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || AUTHOR_LAST_NAME AS AUTHOR_NAME
FROM Authors
WHERE AUTHOR_ID = (SELECT AUTHOR_ID
                   FROM Books
                   GROUP BY AUTHOR_ID
                   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                   FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
                  );
```

EDIT:

If you want the actual number, then move the subquery to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT (a.AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || a.AUTHOR_LAST_NAME) AS AUTHOR_NAME, b.num_books_read
FROM Authors a JOIN
     (SELECT AUTHOR_ID, COUNT(*) as num_books_read
      FROM Books
      GROUP BY AUTHOR_ID
      ORDER BY num_books_read DESC
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
     ) b
     ON a.AUTHOR_ID = b.AUTHOR_ID;
```

Comment: Right. This definitely helps, but I need to retrieve the number of books as well.

Answer (score 0):

What about selecting the Author_Id with the number of books written in a subselect and doing an `INNER JOIN` with the Authors table:

```
SELECT A.AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || A.AUTHOR_LAST_NAME AS AUTHOR_NAME  
      ,MAX.CTR
 FROM Authors A
INNER JOIN 
     (
     SELECT AUTHOR_ID
           ,COUNT(*) AS CTR
       FROM Books
   GROUP BY AUTHOR_ID
   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
     ) MAX
   ON MAX.AUTHOR_ID = A.AUTHOR_ID
```

Comment: It doesn't like the syntax for some reason. [Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42X01] Syntax error: Encountered "." at line 2, column 12.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select 
       A.author_first_name || ' ' || A.author_last_name as author_name
       B.total_books number_of_books_written
   from authors A
   inner join (
    select top 1 
        author_id
        , count(*) [total_books] 
    from books 
    group by author_id 
    order by count(*) desc
    ) B on A.author_id = B.author_id
```

Sorry for the formatting, I think this is my first submitted response.

Comment: Unfortunately my Java DB/Derby database doesn't allow the TOP 1 syntax -- only FETCH FIRST _ ROW ONLY. I tried editing the syntax but still no go.